# Removing duplicates from a list of tuples based on one of values

Tags: python, string, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples in format (float,string). How can I remove duplicates from the list that have the same float value?

The list is sorted by the float in descending order. I want to preserve the order.

```
[(0.10507038451969995,
  'Deadly stampede in Shanghai - Emergency personnel help victims.'),
 (0.078586381821416265,
  'Deadly stampede in Shanghai - Police and medical staff help injured people after the stampede.'),
 (0.072031446647399661, '- Emergency personnel help victims.'),
 (0.072031446647399661, 'Emergency personnel help victims.')]
```

Look at the last two.

Comment: Hmmm.. why the downvotes. Please let know if this is already asked somewhere else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` since you have these values sorted already. Here's the data:

```
>>> lot
[(0.10507038451969995, 'Deadly stampede in Shanghai - Emergency personnel help victims.'), 
(0.07858638182141627, 'Deadly stampede in Shanghai - Police and medical staff help injured people after the stampede.'), 
(0.07203144664739966, '- Emergency personnel help victims.'), 
(0.07203144664739966, 'Emergency personnel help victims.')]
```

Demonstration:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> [next(t) for _, t in itertools.groupby(lot, lambda x: x[0])]
[(0.10507038451969995,
  'Deadly stampede in Shanghai - Emergency personnel help victims.'),
 (0.07858638182141627,
  'Deadly stampede in Shanghai - Police and medical staff help injured people after the stampede.'),
 (0.07203144664739966, '- Emergency personnel help victims.')]
```

This will give you the first of the values grouped together.

Comment: you can use `itemgetter(0)` instead of the lambda

Answer (score 4):

You can create a set of seen values and add tuple only if value is not in `seen`:

```
>>> lst
[(0.10507038451969995,
 'Deadly stampede in Shanghai - Emergency personnel help victims.'),
 (0.078586381821416265,
 'Deadly stampede in Shanghai - Police and medical staff help injured people after the stampede.'),
 (0.072031446647399661, '- Emergency personnel help victims.'),
 (0.072031446647399661, 'Emergency personnel help victims.')]

>>> seen = set()
>>> result = []
>>> for a, b in lst:
...    if not a in seen:
...        seen.add(a)
...        result.append((a, b))
>>> print result

[(0.10507038451969995, 'Deadly stampede in Shanghai - Emergency personnel help victims.'), 
 (0.07858638182141627, 'Deadly stampede in Shanghai - Police and medical staff help injured people after the stampede.'),  
 (0.07203144664739966, '- Emergency personnel help victims.')]
```

Here is another way of doing it with comprehensions:

```
>>> seen = set()
>>> [(a, b) for a, b in lst if not (a in seen or seen.add(a))]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> L = [(0.10507038451969995, 'Deadly stampede in Shanghai - Emergency personnel help victims.'),
...  (0.078586381821416265, 'Deadly stampede in Shanghai - Police and medical staff help injured people after the stampede.'),
...  (0.072031446647399661, '- Emergency personnel help victims.'),
...  (0.072031446647399661, 'Emergency personnel help victims.')]

>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> OrderedDict(L).items()
[(0.10507038451969995, 'Deadly stampede in Shanghai - Emergency personnel help victims.'),
 (0.07858638182141627, 'Deadly stampede in Shanghai - Police and medical staff help injured people after the stampede.'),
 (0.07203144664739966, 'Emergency personnel help victims.')]
```